# Hide toolbar on inline edit rich text fields (or display as standard text)

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport, richtextarea

I am using the inline edit feature of `<apex:inputField>` fields on my cardwall visualforce page as you see here:

[image]

As you see the RTF toolbar is not using the available space in an "optimal" way.
**Is there any (even Javascript hacks allowed here) way to minimize or hide the RTF toolbar? The best option would be to display like a regular long text field. Is that possible?**

Comment: I guess I have done it once. Have you tried setting up the styles for the related divs? Set the display property to None.